# Incomplete popup issue at the first time completion when I use company-box

Tags: company-mode, company

I have an incomplete first-time popup window when installing the company-box plugin. The width of the auto-completion popup that appears the first time is too small In a way that the text of the list entries isn't shown. Do you have any idea how to fix the issue?

[image: The red arrow shows what I mean]

My config:

```
;;; init.el --- My GNU Emacs config
;;; Commentary:

;;; Code:

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;; We up the gc threshold to temporarily prevent it from running, then reset it later by
;; enabling `gcmh-mode'. Not resetting it will cause stuttering/freezes.
(setq gc-cons-threshold most-positive-fixnum)

;; https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/speed-up-emacs-libjansson-native-elisp-compilation
(if (and (fboundp 'native-comp-available-p)
         (native-comp-available-p))
    (setq comp-deferred-compilation t
          package-native-compile t)
  (message "Native complation is *not* available, lsp performance will suffer..."))

(unless (functionp 'json-serialize)
  (message "Native JSON is *not* available, lsp performance will suffer..."))

;; Increase the amount of data which Emacs reads from the process.
(setq read-process-output-max (* 1024 1024)) ;; 1mb

;; Do not steal focus while doing async compilations.
(setq warning-suppress-types '((comp)))

(setq comp-deferred-compilation t)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;; Use straight.el for package management
(defvar bootstrap-version)
(let ((bootstrap-file
       (expand-file-name "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el" user-emacs-directory))
      (bootstrap-version 6))
  (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
    (with-current-buffer
        (url-retrieve-synchronously
         "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/radian-software/straight.el/develop/install.el"
         'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (eval-print-last-sexp)))
  (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))

;; Install use-package using straight.el
(straight-use-package 'use-package)

;; Configure use-package to use straight.el by default
(use-package straight
  :custom
  (straight-use-package-by-default t))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;;; Generic stuff

;; GCMH - the Garbage Collector Magic Hack
(use-package gcmh
  :diminish
  :custom
  (gcmh-idle-delay 1000)
  (gcmh-high-cons-threshold (* 16 1024 1024)) ;; 16 MB
  :hook (after-init . gcmh-mode))

(setq-default shell-file-name "/bin/zsh")

;; UTF-8 everywhere
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
;; Backwards compatibility as default-buffer-file-coding-system
;; is deprecated in 23.2.
(if (boundp 'buffer-file-coding-system)
    (setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)
  (setq default-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8))

;; Treat clipboard input as UTF-8 string first; compound text next, etc.
(setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;;; User experience

;; Disable startup screen
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)

;; Disable menu bar, scroll bar, tool bar, and tooltips
(menu-bar-mode -1)
(scroll-bar-mode -1)
(tool-bar-mode -1)
(tooltip-mode -1)

;; Disable dialog boxes
(setq use-dialog-box nil)

;; Set custom color scheme
(use-package doom-themes)
(use-package doom-moonfly-theme
  :straight (:host github :repo "stackmystack/doom-moonfly-theme"
           :branch "master"))
(load-theme 'doom-moonfly t)

;; Set default font
(set-face-attribute 'default nil
            :family "MesloLGS Nerd Font Mono"
            :height 130
            :weight 'normal
            :width 'normal)

;; Disable annoying bell
(setq ring-bell-function 'ignore)

;; Nice icons
(use-package all-the-icons
  :if (display-graphic-p))

;; Custom modeline
(use-package doom-modeline
  :ensure t
  :hook (after-init . doom-modeline-mode))
(setq inhibit-compacting-font-caches t)

;; Always ask using y or n instead yes or no
(defalias 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;;; Programming & Sysadmin

;; Display line numbers
(require 'display-line-numbers)

(defcustom display-line-numbers-exempt-modes
  '(vterm-mode eshell-mode shell-mode term-mode ansi-term-mode)
  "Major modes on which to disable line numbers."
  :group 'display-line-numbers
  :type 'list
  :version "green")

(defun display-line-numbers--turn-on ()
  "Turn on line numbers except for certain major modes.
Exempt major modes are defined in `display-line-numbers-exempt-modes'."
  (unless (or (minibufferp)
              (member major-mode display-line-numbers-exempt-modes))
    (display-line-numbers-mode)))

(column-number-mode)
(global-display-line-numbers-mode)

;; Disable line numbers for some modes
(dolist (mode '(org-mode-hook
                term-mode-hook
                shell-mode-hook
            ;treemacs-mode-hook
                eshell-mode-hook))
  (add-hook mode (lambda () (display-line-numbers-mode 0))))

;; Auto close bracket insertion
(electric-pair-mode 1)

;; C-x C-; is not properly handled in terminal emulator so let's
;; add custom key binding for toggling comments in line
(defun toggle-comment-on-line ()
  "Comment or uncomment current line."
  (interactive)
  (comment-or-uncomment-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c ;") #'toggle-comment-on-line)

;; Change indentation level for languages with C-like syntax
(setq-default c-basic-offset 4)

;; Various modes
(use-package etc-sudoers-mode)
(use-package systemd)

;; Language server protocol
(use-package lsp-mode
  :init
  (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")
  :hook ((c-mode . lsp)
     (c++-mode . lsp)
     ;; (python-mode . lsp)
     ;; (ruby-mode . lsp)
     ;; (html-mode . lsp)
     ;; (css-mode . lsp)
     ;; (js-mode . lsp)
     ;; (js-jsx-mode . lsp)
     ;; (xml-mode . lsp)
     ;; (systemd-mode . lsp)
     (lisp-interaction-mode . nil))
  :commands lsp
  ;; :custom
  ;; (lsp-auto-guess-root t)
  ;; (lsp-log-io t)
  ;; (lsp-idle-delay 0.5)
  ;; (lsp-prefer-flymake nil))
  ;; (lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-segments '(path-up-to-project file symbols)))
)

;; UI enchancements
(use-package lsp-ui
  :after (lsp-mode)
  :commands lsp-ui-mode
  :hook (lsp-mode . lsp-ui-mode))

;; Auto completion engine
(use-package company
  :after lsp-mode
  :init
  (setq company-format-margin-function nil)
  ;; (setq company-format-margin-function #'company-vscode-dark-icons-margin)
  :bind
  (:map company-active-map
    ("<tab>" . company-complete-selection))
  (:map lsp-mode-map
    ("<tab>" . company-indent-or-complete-common))
  :custom
  (company-minimum-prefix-length 1)
  (company-idle-delay 0.0) ;; default is 0.2
  :hook ((text-mode . company-mode)
     (prog-mode . company-mode)
         (org-mode . company-mode)
;    (company-mode . yas-minor-mode)
     (lsp-mode . company-mode)))

(use-package company-box
   :hook ((company-mode . company-box-mode)))

;; Error suggestions
(use-package flycheck
  :ensure t
  :init (global-flycheck-mode))

(use-package flycheck-color-mode-line)
(eval-after-load "flycheck"
  '(add-hook 'flycheck-mode-hook 'flycheck-color-mode-line-mode))

(use-package flycheck-pos-tip)
(with-eval-after-load 'flycheck
  (flycheck-pos-tip-mode))

(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             `(,(rx bos "*Flycheck errors*" eos)
              (display-buffer-reuse-window
               display-buffer-in-side-window)
              (side            . bottom)
              (reusable-frames . visible)
              (window-height   . 0.33)))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(provide 'init)
;;; init.el ends here
```

Comment: Can you say what's incomplete/wrong? Don't rely on readers interpreting a screenshot in a way that may be obvious to you. Thx.

Comment: I have edited this post. Look now

Comment: Thank you!.....

Comment: Similar question was asked (not resolved) at the [company-box repo](https://github.com/sebastiencs/company-box/issues/154). That's probably a better place to report the issue. Narrow down your config to absolutely necessary part to reproduce the issue. For loading Emacs without your init file use `emacs -Q`.